# Why I'm losing my downloaded data every time I disconnect to the server

Tags: google-colaboratory

I ran thins command 
!git clone https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech
And I got what I wanted.
Unfortunately, next day all data I downloaded on my account is gone, why?
Do I need to download and install libs every time I open colab notebook?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can run at most 12 hours, then the machine is shutdown. You get a new one next time.

So, yes, you need to git clone and pip install again, after a day.